# Olingo - OData Help needed?

Tags: odata, olingo

Am pretty new to OData.
Per my internet reading what I've gathered is Apache Olingo is better (vs OData4j) for Java implementation of OData service and OData consumer.

Can you please help me with sample code of Olingo service and Olingo consumer?

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Have a good one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll want to consult Olingo's documentation [here](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/index.html). Their documentation is alright for basics but once you start extending it there's not much out there. As you can tell from no one answering this for 18 hours OData doesn't seem to be a hot topic right now.

If you want to create a basic service without JPA this is a good resource: [OData Service with Olingo](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/read/tutorial_read.html)

If you want to create an OData service that uses JPA this is a good resource: [OData JPA Web App](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/CreateWebApp.html). Also this one is helpful [Olingo OData with MySQL](http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server).

Here's a document on how to create a client: [Olingo Client](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/OlingoV2BasicClientSample.html) We actually use Excel as a client which is quite nice for Excel users. However, there are times when Excel has compatibility issues with certain features (EDM Complex Types). Here's some good documentation on how to use [Excel and OData](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-tutorial-analyzing-sales-data-from-excel-and-an-odata-feed/)

Comment: Thanks Brod for your feedback.  Any identified drawbacks around ODATA that it is not as hot any more?  Are there other better alternatives out there now?     Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, if you like my answer it would be great if you'd accept it as the answer :) There are definitely alternatives to OData. It all depends what you want to do. Generic rest services are a good route. If you are looking for a query type Rest service GraphQL is pretty sweet. It was developed at Facebook. There are a few Java implementations like this one on GitHub: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java